# Google Chrome in Kubuntu 18.04 does not scale to 1.5x

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, display-resolution

I installed Google Chrome on Kubuntu 18.04 running a display resolution of 3840x2160.  Google chrome is not starting at 1.5x scale, even with the *--force-device-scale-factor=1.5* flag.    It is starting at scale-factor=1, and giving me the following error:

```
ray@ray-ThinkStation-S30:~/snap/atom$ google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor=1.5

(google-chrome:14758): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:31:02.865: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:68:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-x is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(google-chrome:14758): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:31:02.865: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:69:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-y is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(google-chrome:14758): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:31:02.865: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:73:46: The style property GtkScrolledWindow:scrollbars-within-bevel is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
Opening in existing browser session.
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Edit: Atom starts using this flag and is scaled at 1.5x

Answer (score 0):

Go to KDE settings and change display sizing to 150%.  This will force Chrome and other electron based apps to resize to hidpi displays.